# Checking to see if last 2 numbers in array both exist in 2D array using loops

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two arrays, one singular and the other 2 dimensional.

```
int[][] array1 = { 
    new int [] {1, 22, 3, 44, 5, 66},
    new int [] {11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66},
    new int [] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
};

int[] array2 = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 5, 66}
```

I need to create a loop which searches the array1 for both the 2nd last digits in array2, so it would return how many times an array with array1 contains both 5 and 66, which is 1, as the other two only contain 1 of each number.

I already managed to write a function which returns how many times array2 as a whole exists in array1, this new function is effectively a refinement of that.

```
for (int a = 0; a < array1[i].Length; a++) 
{                   
    for (int b = 0; b < array2.Length; b++)
    {   
        if (array2[c] == array1[a][b])                            
            count++;

        temp[b] = array1[a][b];
    }
}
```

I feel all would be needed to search for just the last two digits is a slight change to this function, I tried to add in another loop but that didn't work either. How would I go about doing this? I'm using loops and not Contains for a reason since i'm still learning the basics.

Comment: Does it matter which position the two digits occur in the 2D array (e.g. only at the end) or can the occur in any position?

Comment: @MatthewWatson not at all, for example the array (5, 74, 73, 92, 48, 66) would still count++, i'm just trying to look for arrays where both numbers exist in no particular order. Sort of like supp numbers in a lottery.

Comment: @RobertPaulson Then, you can try my answer.

Comment: @RobertPaulson I have added [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d8Y32t) in my answer for complete code.

Answer (score 3):

The one thing is not clear in question that, ***does it matter which position the two digits occur in the 2D array?***
If ithis is not the case, then you can use [`Intersect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which produces the set intersection of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values:

```
var result = array1.Count(x => x.Intersect(array2.Reverse().Take(2)).Count() == 2);
```

If you have paid an attention we have used this line, for getting last two elements of `array1`:

```
array1.Reverse().Take(2);
```

**[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d8Y32t)**

***Additional:***

If you want to find if ***last two elements of arrays in 2D array*** is equal to last two elements of `array1`, then you can try LINQ solution:

```
var result = array1.Count(x=> x.Reverse().Take(2).SequenceEqual(array2.Reverse().Take(2)));
```

***Explanation of used extension methods:***
[`Reverse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358497(v=vs.100).aspx) inverts the order of the elements in a sequence.

[`Take()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a sequence.

[`SequenceEqual()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) determines whether two sequences are equal by comparing the elements by using the default equality comparer for their type.

After getting last two elements of both arrays, we will use `SequenceEqual()` to determine if both arrays are equal.

Comment: having trouble implementing this in the loop

Comment: @RobertPaulson You must not include this into the loop. This line is enough. Dont't forget to include `using Sytem.Linq`

Comment: @RobertPaulson Check my update in my answer which gives link to Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = array1.Where((x) => (x.Contains(array2.Last()) && x.Contains(array2[array2.Length - 2]))).Count();
```

**Explaination:**

- array1.Where takes every subarray of array1 and filters the ones that
     meet a certain condition.
- The condition being every subarray of
     array1 contains the last && next-to-last element of array2.
- The
     Count() methods returns the number of subarrays that meet the
     conditions

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description` that helps to explain your code.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of target values and then count the number of times that the intersection of that array with each subarray in the 2D array contains all the items in the target array:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            int[][] array1 =
            { 
                new [] {1, 22, 3, 44, 5, 66},
                new [] {11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66},
                new [] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
                new [] {1, 66, 3, 4, 5, 6} // This one has the target items out of order.
            };

            int[] array2 = {1, 2, 3, 5, 66};

            // Extract the targets like this; it avoids making a copy
            // of array2 which occurs if you use IEnumerable.Reverse().

            int[] targets = {array2[array2.Length - 2], array2[array2.Length - 1]};

            // Count the number of times that each subarray in array1 includes
            // all the items in targets:

            int count = array1.Count(array => array.Intersect(targets).Count() == targets.Length);

            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
    }
}
```